# Probability of $ 7$ white chessboard squares without neighbours

Tags: combinatorics

If we start with a $2\times 30$ chessboard and we remove $15$ black squares, how can I find the probability that we get $7$ white squares which don't have any neighbours? (A white square will have no neighbours if all of the black squares adjoining it are removed).

Comment: I assume that the black squares are selected uniformly, but are you looking for the probability that *at least* 7 white squares are isolated, or that *exactly* 7 white squares are isolated?

Comment: Excactly 7 white squares are isolated....

Comment: I would start with a smaller problem. Solving it might give you an idea of how to solve the original, or give you a feel for how hard the original is.

Answer (score 0):

If we label the columns where we delete the black square with an `x` and the ones where we don't with a `.` then we get a 30-character string containing 15 `x` and 15 `.`

Prepend and postpend `x` to handle the boundary cases (so that the end white squares are isolated respectively by a leading and trailing `xxx`)

Then each maximal non-overlapping substring of the form `x`$^{2+n}$ corresponds to $n$ isolated white squares.

Possible continuations:

1. Partitions of 7. There are 15 partitions of 7, of which 4 would require more than 15 deleted squares (e.g. $7 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2$ requires three runs of three and two runs of four, for a total of 17 deleted squares), so that leaves 11 cases to handle. They might be grouped with some thought.
2. Create a recurrence in terms of the length of the board, the number of squares to delete, and the number of white squares to isolate.